# Why small-6 is not working in this Foundation 6.4 Code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I was working on a layout using **Zurb Foundation 6.4** Framework where I have 3 Cards having 3 images of 320x180 px each in each column. I want when it will viewed in small screen then there will be two cards in each row.

It is working as expected for large view- 3 columns. But in small view it should have 2 columns or cards but it is showing 1 card or 1 column.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/coolsaint/pen/LzbpOy

I am not being able to figure out what is happening. Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" />

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x small-6 large-4 align-center">


    <div class="cell shrink">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `small-6 large-4` class in `cell` class element like this,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" />

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x align-center">


    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell shrink small-6 large-4">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />

      </div>
    </div>
    


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working in small screen but in large screen images are getting stretched.

Comment: it is default card style in foundation. If you want to show images actual size in large screen then use 
`.card img { margin: auto; }`

Comment: It is creating margin in both sides of the images. I don't want margin around images.

Comment: I think you get your answer. For image issue you can ask separately. I hope you will get answer.